# How to check if string is in a list inside a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm trying to validate `IF` a string exists inside a `List<string>`. But the `List<string>` is inside `List<List<string>>`..

Kindly check my `code` below. It throws an `ArgumentException`.

```
loadTestList = new List<List<string>>();

loadTestList.ElementAt(loadTestSelect.SelectedIndex - 1).Contains(scorecardName);
```

Take note `loadTestSelect` is a **dropdown/select** that the user chooses from. The user chooses the `List<string>` that would be validated.

`scoreCardName` is the string that I want to search.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How it is related to javascript and jquery?

Comment: only select the matching tags to your question. people will come to answer  you who don't have c# knowledge.

Comment: @Sagar V my validation function is on client-side. the code with Contains above is enclosed with `<% %>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if(loadTestList.Any(x => x.Contains(scorecardName))
{
   // Proceed specified item is present in one sublist
}
```

Or the following if you want to check for contains only in a specified sublist based on the selected index from the `loadTestSelect`

```
if(loadTestList[loadTestSelect.SelectedIndex].Contains(scorecardName))
{
   // Proceed specified item is present 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try *Linq* with `Any()` put *twice*:

```
var loadTestList = new List<List<string>>() {
  new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c"},
  new List<string>() {"la-la-la"},
  new List<string>(),
  null,
  new List<string>() {"test", null, "sample"},
};

string scorecardName = "am"; // should be found in the "sample" 

var exists = loadTestList
  .Any(list => list != null && 
               list.Any(item => item != null && 
                                item.Contains(scorecardName)));
```